# WCF WebHttp Services create proxy class

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest

i was uisng this template: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fbc7e5c1-a0d2-41bd-9d7b-e54c845394cd , created my service, everything ok.

The problem is use it in an application, how I can use the xsd.exe and the schema to generate client proxy classes. which i know it will generate something like this: http://www.ageektrapped.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/serializer/generated.cs.html .

When i learn this, i used the visual studio command prompt to generate the class, but now i can't remember how it is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, created a xsd file, with the response Xml Schema, available at the http://localhost:0000/Service1/help/operations/GetCollection, and then in the command line used the xsd /c service1.xsd to generate the .cs file.

Answer (score 0):

[How to: Create a Windows Communication Foundation Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133.aspx)

Comment: Not exacly what i was looking for, my service doesn't have a svc file and a config, is like this: http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/08/21/restful-wcf-services-with-no-svc-file-and-no-config.aspx